# How to I get suspend/hibernate working with my proprietary NVIDIA driver?

Tags: nvidia, graphics, suspend, sony, vaio

I'm using a Sony Vaio Z. (VPCZ122GX to be precise)
I have to use a modded kernel to boot and then reboot into the new kernel in order to get accelerated graphics. This is due to the nature of the hardware graphics chip switcher. I've got the NVIDIA graphics working fine, except for suspend/hibernate. When I suspend it goes to sleep, however, when I open the lid and press the power button, the light comes back on, but I have nothing on my screen. Its just black. I can't even enter tty1. I'd appreciate any possible solutions to my problem.

Comment: What is your modded kernel, exactly (i.e. where did you download it or how did you compile it)? Other than that, are you using the Ubuntu-shipped kernel and driver? Which Ubuntu release (lucid, natty, other)?

Comment: I'm using the modded 2.6.28.10-vaioZ kernel from http://www.voip-x.co.uk/files/adam/ to do the restarting part, and then booting into the current kernel (whatever that one is), and I'm running natty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pm-powersave` runs scripts when you suspend/unsuspend. You should check `pm-powersave`'s scripts, and make sure they don't do unsymmetric things to your graphics. I went into more detail in [Why is wireless down/strange after switching to battery or closing/opening the lid?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65632/why-is-wireless-down-strange-after-switching-to-battery)